# How to count an overall total of a buyer and the cost

Tags: database, oracle

I would like to make a table that will look like this, but I am not sure on how to fix my problems nor do a count on the buyer and overall total. If you can please help

Buyer     |department  |procure  |overall  total

Steve (3) |IT          |AWD      |$70.00

John (2)  |Maint       |RWD      |$10.00

Mark (5)   |Executive  |Awd      |$700.00

but the only thing I know how to do is get a chart that says

Steve| IT  | AWD |$25

Steve| IT  | AWD |$25

Steve| IT  | AWD |$25

John| Maint| RWD |$7

John| maint |RWD| $3

Mark| Executive|AWD|$100

Mark| Executive|AWD|$100

Mark| Executive|AWD|$100

Mark| Executive|AWD|$300

Mark| Executive|AWD|$100

MY CODE LOOKS LIKES THIS :

```
SELECT
  SSU.P_HEADER.BUYER,
  SSU.P_HEADER.DEPT_ID,
  SSU.P_HEADER.PROCURE_TYPE,

    enter code here

    (SSU.P_LINE.QUANTITY* SSU.P_LINE.COST) AS TOTAL


FROM 
        SSU.P_HEADER INNER JOIN SSU.P_LINE ON SSU.P_HEADER.TRX = SSU.P_LINE.TRX

WHERE
        SSU.P_HEADER.PROCURE_TYPE= 'AWD'
        OR SSU.P_HEADER.PROCURE_TYPE= 'REQ'
    sum( buyer= total)

ORDER BY BUYER DESC

    enter code here
```

Comment: try http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to make your table in a readable format.   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the metadata and data I used to (I believe) give you what you are looking for (NOTE: if not it will give you a start):

```
create table buyers (buyer varchar2(100), department varchar2(100), procure varchar2(100), cost integer);

insert into buyers values ('Steve', 'IT', 'AWD', 25);
insert into buyers values ('Steve', 'IT', 'AWD', 25);
insert into buyers values ('Steve', 'IT', 'AWD', 25);
insert into buyers values ('John', 'Maint', 'RWD', 7);
insert into buyers values ('John', 'Maint', 'RWD', 3);
insert into buyers values ('Mark', 'Executive', 'AWD', 100);
insert into buyers values ('Mark', 'Executive', 'AWD', 100);
insert into buyers values ('Mark', 'Executive', 'AWD', 100);
insert into buyers values ('Mark', 'Executive', 'AWD', 300);
insert into buyers values ('Mark', 'Executive', 'AWD', 100);
```

And here's the SELECT to get your results:

```
select buyer, department, procure, sum(cost) as overall_total
from buyers
group by buyer, department, procure;
```

And here is your results:

[image]

If you want those buyer count numbers in () then the SELECT you could use would be:

```
select b.buyer || ' (' || a.buyer_cnt || ')' as buyer, department, procure, sum(cost) as overall_total
from buyers b,
     (select count(*) buyer_cnt, buyer
      from buyers
      group by buyer
      ) a
where b.buyer = a.buyer
group by b.buyer || ' (' || a.buyer_cnt || ')', department, procure;
```

And then your result set will look like this:

[image]